# how do sub classes interact with super classes

Tags: java

The question i'm asking is can you have the following. super is the super class of sub

```
super thing = new sub();
```

and then call a method from the sub class

Comment: Please read a basic Java tutorial on classes and inheritance.

Comment: Mother class methods are available in sub class ,as long as methods are not "private"

Comment: that not what i'm asking

Comment: maybe this will help
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
it explain it quite well

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
{
    public void foo() { System.out.println("foo"); }
    public void baz() { System.out.println("baz"); }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void foo() { System.out.println("fizz"); }
    public void bar() { System.out.println("bar"); }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A obj1 = new A();
        A obj2 = new B();
        obj1.foo(); // prints "foo"
        obj1.baz(); // prints "baz"

        obj2.foo(); // prints "fizz"
        obj2.baz(); // prints "baz"
        obj2.bar(); // compile error

        ((B)obj2).bar(); // prints "bar"
        ((B)obj1).bar(); // runtime error
    }
}
```

As you can see, an object of type `A` initialized as a `B` will call any overridden methods in `B`, but *new* methods in `B` can't be seen. Methods that aren't overridden will use the version in the super class.

You can cast a class to something more specific (object declared as the superclass to the subclass type), but if the object isn't *actually* an instance of the more-specific type, you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: That is good, but I -think- the OP is actually looking for an upcasting example. He has A and he wants to call a method from B anyway.

Comment: @Gimby, The wouldn't be upcasting, that would be normal type-casting. I'll add it to my answer, though.